# Issues in creating a 'Reusable workflow' from 'List Workflow'

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have to create a 'Reusable workflow' from 'List Workflow'.

The first action to create should be like the 'first image'. It shows the operator condition with left and right operand

[image: First Image]

But,when i tried to create like this it's getting like the second one.
and also what does the 'Run action.Nintex.Workflow' that mean how to get this in my workflow.

[image: Second Image]

what are the things I have to do to create a workflow like first Image.
Any suggestions,I'm newbie to share point. 
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

I have added the first Image too.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The first image does not exists now, please provide your first image again.

In SharePoint designer, you can create SharePoint 2010/2013 platform workflow, to create Nintex workflow, you need to use third party workflow tool Nintex.